# Mockito mocking method with this parameter

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have scenario when I want mock a method with this parameter, my method looks like below

```
this.listener = myCustomFactory.buildCustomListener(this);
```

I have mocked instance of myCustomFactory as given below

```
@Mock
MyCustomFactory myCustomFactory;
```

Is it possible to mock method with this parameter. 'this' refer the class for which I am writing unit test, I am creating reference for that class

```
Mockito.when(this.myCustomFactory.buildCustomListener(this.myClassObjectToBeTested).thenReturn(this.mockedListener);
```

Comment: Yes. Did you try it? Was there an error? It should work.

Comment: yes it returns null,  I also tried with Mockito.any()

Comment: @Tunaki, thanks for reply, please see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Mockito.any(Class<T> clazz)`  solved the issue

Mockito.when(this.myCustomFactory.buildCustomListener(Mockito.any(MyClassToBeTested.class)).thenReturn(this.mockedListener);